# File.exists() always returns false in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-file

It's been a hard day trying to figure this out. I am trying to open a downloaded PDF using an Intent. The PDF is saved to default downloads folder.

Soon after download, I check for file existence.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName.trim());

if(file.exists()) {
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(d);
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

The file location is /mnt/sdcard/Download/fileName.pdf

However, the file.exists() always returns false even though it exists on sdcard. I checked for many posts in the internet. Somebody answered removing **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** worked for them. I am using launchMode="singleTop"

Here are the permissions on the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am unable to find a solution for the current community posts which is why I am here.

What am I missing? Could anyone tell me what acts unusual ?

**SOLVED**

After hours of investing, I found a workaround. Upon opening the file, I redirect it to downloads folder.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
startActivity(intent);
```

That finally solved it!!!

Thanks for all the inputs!

Comment: Try to log the path Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + filename and check with your downloads folder

Comment: Did you add permission to acces the file in sdcard?

Comment: @Arju lemme have look now...

Comment: try to log the whole file path including the filename , Lets make sure of it

Comment: the path is just the same. I can see the pdf in there!

Comment: can you post the path you get

Comment: @Arju the funny part is there is no exception. File.exists() always returns false!